# Cannot move virtual function outside header

Tags: c++, function, visual-c++, syntax, compilation

I have a C++ class header that defines many functions inline. I want to move these functions outside the header and into a seperate `.cpp` file to speeden up the compile. Although I can move normal functions into a seperate file and keep only the function deceleration in the header, when I try to move virtual functions into the `.cpp` I get the following error:

> Error 2 - error C2723: 'virtual' storage-class specifier illegal on function definition

How do I do that? The function is as follows:

```
 virtual void SoundMixerSub::SetFilters(const MixerFilter& f)
 { 
....
 }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As it says, you can't have `virtual` on the function definition outside the class, as per §7.1.2:

> The `virtual` specifier shall be used only in the initial declaration of a non-static class member function

Keep the `virtual` on the declaration and remove it from the definition. So in the header file:

```
class SoundMixerSub : ...
{
  // ...
  virtual void SetFilters(const MixerFilter&);
  // ...
};
```

Then in the implementation file:

```
void SoundMixerSub::SetFilters(const MixerFilter& f)
{ 
  // ...
}
```

Comment: To add some points : If you have default values specified for arguments, they must be removed in the implementation.

Comment: @Geotarget - or removed in the declaration; of course, that would usually be pointless. `<g>`